# Failure to run terminal-notifier (Ruby app) from a Launch Agent in OSX. Environment variable problems?

Tags: ruby, macos, notifications, osx-mountain-lion, launchd

I'd like to periodically pop up a notification (I have a "current task" I'd like to display, in a Pomodoro style app). I am attempting to use a user Launch Agent to schedule the task, which works successfully for running `.sh` or `.py` scripts. However, I'm not able to schedule the `terminal-notifier` to successfully launches. A possible cause from other reading is that the Environment variables are different for the Launch Agent process than the usual logged in user's Environment.

I install terminal-notifier via `gem install terminal-notifier`

```
myusername@Nathans-MacBook-Pro~/bin$ which terminal-notifier 
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/terminal-notifier
```

Here's my shell script `reminder.sh`:

```
#!/bin/sh
date >>/tmp/reminder.log
terminal-notifier -message "message txt" -title "title txt"
```

Running this script directly from the Terminal works as expected: a time-stamp is logged in `reminder.log` and the notification pop-up appears. However, when I try to run it via launch-agent it fails.

I put in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/` a file `com.myusername.Reminder.plist` with the following contents.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.myusername.Reminder</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/Users/myusername/bin/reminder.sh</string>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>10</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

After creating this file I then load it

`launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.myusername.Reminder.plist`

and (not sure if needed, as it includes RunAtLoad)

`launchctl start com.myusername.Reminder`

While it successfully logs a timestamp to the file every 10 seconds, it doesn't trigger a notification.

Any tips on how to make this successfully run?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you need any more help with this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is right. launchd(8) has no idea where to find `terminal-notifier`. The simple solution is to call `terminal-notifier` with an absolute path. Adjust your shell script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
date >>/tmp/reminder.log
/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin/terminal-notifier -message "message txt" -title "title txt"
```

Alternatively you can always extend the `PATH` environment variable using the launchd(8) key `EnvironmentVariables`. The corresponding section in your job definition should look like this:

```
<key>EnvironmentVariables</key>
<dict>
    <key>PATH</key>
    <string>/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/bin</string>
</dict>
```